# OCR within an x,y window of a pdf

Tags: pdf, ocr

I need to find an open source or linux based utility that allows me to set an x,y coordinate in a setup file. I would like to then sequentially open pdf's and look in the documents for first, last name and account number and save the file with a file name consisting of last name and file number.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to read some of these answers first :

- [A Java Library for text extraction from PDF documents preserving empty spaces and lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606936/a-java-library-for-text-extraction-from-pdf-documents-preserving-empty-spaces-and)
- [How to extract text from a PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650957/recommendations-for-pdf-text-extraction)
- [How-to extract text from a pdf doc within a specific rectangular region?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297931/how-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf-doc-within-a-specific-rectangular-region/4300241#4300241)

The answers above are not Linux specific.

Most PDF documents do not need to be OCR'ed as the text is contained within the PDF.  The hard part is extracting in.  The Java version of iText (http://itextpdf.com/)  is probably the best toolkit under Linux to extract the PDF text strings.  Another option may be http://pdfbox.apache.org/

If the text you need to extract is actually an image then you will probably need to convert the whole PDF page to image format such as TIFF and pass that into an OCR engine such as Google Tesseract OCR.